# Pythonic way to always get a list

Tags: python

Is there a standard library function or more pythonic way to do this ?

```
def itemize(i):
    if type(i) is list:
        return i
    return [i]
```

Context:

Useful in db (nosql style) migrations from single value to a list

```
doc = <get doc from db>
for i in itemize(doc.var1):
    #blah
```

or

```
doc.var1 = itemize(doc.var1)
```

Comment: Doing this isn't very pythonic.  In a lot of situations, a `tuple` will work instead of a list.  This also won't pass subclasses.

Comment: Do you really want a list or do you just want something that is sequenceable? iterable? etc.  Depending on specific types is likely to get you into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, enforcing this sort of thing is a bad idea.  In many cases, the most pythonic thing you can do is check if your item is a *sequence*:

```
import collections
def to_sequence(item):
    return item if isinstance(item,collections.Sequence) else [item]
```

One instance where this passes something that you *may not want to pass* is with strings ... strings are sequences, so `to_sequence('foo')` will return `'foo'`, not `['foo']` -- but it's unlikely that you want it to be `['f','o','o']` either ... so you might need to special case for that if it's desired.

One simple fix for that would be (for python2.x):

```
import collections
def to_sequence(item):
    return item if isinstance(item,collections.Sequence) and hasattr(item,'__iter__') else [item]
```

But again, usually the "pythonic" thing to do is to defer this sort of checking and try to use the object in some context -- if it fails, then you can do something to react.

Comment: To avoid strings, `hasattr(item, '__iter__')` would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: @sr2222 -- Yep, it would ... I've always wondered how you can iterate over strings when they don't have `__iter__`.  At some point I'll probably go to try to look it up ...

Comment: Though you could also accomplish the same thing as in your original with `try:` `return list(item)` `except TypeError:` `return [item]`.  Strictly speaking, I think that is more Pythonic (being duck-type-y), but really, it boils down to style.

Comment: Unfortunately the `hasattr` trick doesn't work in Python 3.  The one place I regularly use this listify idiom is when writing convenience wrappers which accept either a string or a sequence of strings.  I usually wind up special-casing strings..

Comment: @sr2222 -- `list('foo')` -> `['f','o','o']` which is almost certainly not what OP wants ...

Comment: @DSM -- Oh python3!  garg -- You can't even write a check which does it properly for python2 and python3 ... `isinstance(item,str)`, `isinstance(item,basestring)` ...

Comment: @mgilson I was merely pointing out an arguably more Pythonic way to do what you did in your original answer, not suggesting it would handle the string special case.  Also, isn't the `isinstance` redundant in the `hasattr` example?

Comment: @sr2222 -- Nope, Lots of things have `__iter__` that aren't sequences.  sequences also have a size (`__len__`) associated with them for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
def itemize(i):
    try:
        return list(i) # Will return a list if provided an iterable
    except TypeError:
        return [i]
```

Not entirely sure why you think you need this though, it might be a problem somewhere else that you actually need that.

Comment: As a side note, this behaves extremely differently than OP's code if you pass in a string ... OP's code:  `itemize('foo') -> ['foo']`, your code:  `itemize('foo') -> ['f','o','o']`

Answer (score 2):

If you have to type check (which you should generally avoid in python, I'd love to see some context for the need here) you can get away with this shorthand that uses `isinstance` which is preferable.

```
def makelist(i):
  return i if isinstance(i, list) else [i]
```

Comment: In this case `isinstance` is superior because it allows you to provide a tuple as the second argument of possible exclusions to your rule, as well as supporting subclasses if you're working with something derived from `list` or that uses a meta class of some kind.